# Avoid duplicate coding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm working on some project which involves many forms .. in each form i have to import an excel into datagrid using below code ..  i dont want to duplicate the code for each form .. planning to create module so that i can call the function from each form to import the excel data into datagrid .

```
   Try
            With Form1.OpenFileDialog1
                .Title = "Please open the STM_Ticket_Template"
                .Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx"
                If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    Dim fn1 As String = .FileName.ToString
                    Dim oledbCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + fn1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
                    conDB = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(oledbCon)
                    adap = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [SAM_TICKETS$]", conDB)
                    adap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Excel")
                    dSet = New DataSet
                    adap.Fill(dSet)
                    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables(0)
                End If
            End With
            Dim msg As String = MsgBox("Template successfully loaded", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Creation Template")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Load Error..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

is there any way to do this ?.

any suggestion appreciated :)

Comment: How about you abstract your code out into a module that you can share the common functionality between your forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a function:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Function GetExcelTable() AS DataTable
    Dim od As OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    od.ShowDialog
    try
        With od
                .Title = "Please open the STM_Ticket_Template"
                .Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx"
                If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    Dim fn1 As String = .FileName.ToString
                    Dim oledbCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + fn1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
                    conDB = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(oledbCon)
                    adap = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [SAM_TICKETS$]", conDB)
                    adap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Excel")
                    dSet = New DataSet
                    adap.Fill(dSet)
                    Return dSet.Tables(0)
                End If
            End With
            Dim msg As String = MsgBox("Template successfully loaded", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Creation Template")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Load Error..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString)
        End Try 
End Function
```

and then call it as:

```
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = GetExcelTable()
```

Comment: The code above might not be 100% ready to go. You probably need to have the oledbCon and some else in the Function argument list. But i guess you got what i mean.

Comment: As expected .. code works perfectly. i made some changes as per my need .Thanks for your time :) have a great day

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a pattern you can put into a sub or function and make that call each time you need to call an import:

```
Public Sub ImportForm()
'Import Logic
End Sub
```

Then call `ImportForm()` everywhere you need it.

Comment: Yes you are right .. i know that method will work for sure ..For each i need import the excel data into different datagrid (ex datagridview1,datagridview2,.....) , How to i do that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on [Standard Modules in VB .NET](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets9p7.html).

This will allow you to create your Excel logic in one place and have it be called from multiple forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function like yparask does, but then pass the datagrid

```
Public Function GetExcelTable(Dgv as datagridview) AS boolean

' do your openfile and import stuff here

return true ' succesfull

return false ' unsuccesfull
```